# NodeJS assert.AssertionError: How do I kill it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, ibm-cloud

I am using IBM Bluemix to make a web service for a school project.

I set a localhost to run my code, but I am facing an "assert.AssertionError"  when I type "npm start" in the Windows 10 Command Prompt.

I am facing an assert.AssertionError when I try to run my code.

What is causing this error and how can I get rid of it?

Here is my .js file:

```js
/*eslint-env node*/

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// node.js starter application for Bluemix
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//"Ask" express
var express = require(express);

// HTTP request - duas alternativas
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');

// cfenv provides access to your Cloud Foundry environment
// for more info, see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cfenv
var cfenv = require('cfenv');

// create a new express server 
var app = express();

// serve the files out of ./public as our main files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// get the app environment from Cloud Foundry
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();

//chama o express, que abre o servidor
var express = require('express');

// start server on the specified port and binding host
app.listen(appEnv.port, '0.0.0.0', function() {
    // print a message when the server starts listening
    console.log("server starting on " + appEnv.url);
});


app.get('/home1', function(res){
    http.get('http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/cotacoes/json', function(res){
        var body = '';
        res.on('data', function(chunk){
            body += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function(){
            var json = JSON.parse(body);
        });
        var json = JSON.parse(res);
        var cotacao = json["bovespa"]["cotacao"];

        console.log("A sua cotação é "+cotacao);

    });
});
```

[image: Print of the Assert Error]

Here is a print of the error screen I get when I do "npm start". Please notice that the "C:xxxxx" path is the directory that contains my .js file.

Comment: Shouldn't `var express = require(express);` be `var express = require("express");`?  (although it's already there, a few lines later)  That's the line where the error appears to live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your nodejs application doesn't find 'express' module, so you are facing that issue.

change your line

> var express = require(express);

in

> var express = require('express');

or simply remove that line, as that is a duplicate.
You have already required the module

> //chama o express, que abre o servidor 
>   var express = require('express');